# How to pass to CreateWindow win32 api the title bar string as function param

Tags: winapi

i know i need to use : L"my title" for the second param in the win32 api CreateWindow.
but what is i want to make this parameter dynamic and gets its string from function .
for example this not working the title bar is in Chinese fonts all the time

```
GLboolean esUtil_win32::WinCreate ( ESContext *esContext, const char *title )
{
...
...

   esContext->hWnd = CreateWindow(
                         L"opengles2.0",
                         (LPCTSTR)title,
                         wStyle,
                         0,
                         0,
                         windowRect.right - windowRect.left,
                         windowRect.bottom - windowRect.top,
                         NULL,
                         NULL,
                         hInstance,
                         NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Fundamentally the problem is that `title` is an ANSI (or multi-byte) string and the `CreateWindowW` function expects Unicode strings. There are three ways you can solve this:

1. Change the definition of the `WinCreate` function to take a `const wchar_t* title` parameter instead. This may have repercussions elsewhere in your code, although if the strings passed to this function are always string literals then it's as simple as prefixing them all with `L` to make them wide.
2. Change the `CreateWindow` call to `CreateWindowA`, to explicitly call the ANSI version of the function. This would let you pass `title` to the function without conversion. You would need to remove the `L` from `L"opengles2.0"` if you did this.
3. Convert the `title` string to Unicode before passing it to the function. You can do this using code similar to this:

   ```
   wchar_t wchTitle[256]; // pick a sensible maximum
   MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, title, -1, wchTitle, 256);
   ```

   You would then pass `wchTitle` to the `CreateWindow` function instead of `title`. If `title` is in some other encoding (e.g. UTF-8) you would change the `CP_ACP` value appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Windows uses UTF-16 character encoding, but you are passing a string with some other encoding (`title`). To use this string you need to convert it to UTF-16 first. Call [`MultiByteToWideChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072.aspx) to convert from your source encoding to UTF-16.